# References and resources on hyperspectral (multispectral) image processing

Tags: image-processing, reference-request

Due to my work, I just started studying hyperspectral or multispectral image processing.

I think I have enough programming background and studied mathematics for my degree - it was long time ago though. Since early this year, I have been exposed to image processing in my development work for manufacturing industry. And I got involved in a research project dealing with the subject above.

I wonder if anyone can recommend good references or resources for the subject. Especially, I would like to be familiar with that kind of image data. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't offer you any advice on the topic (other than that it looks really neat and has multiple medical applications!), but it would help those who can answer if you could briefly report what background you *do* have already, so that they won't send you to an intro textbook if you're an expert in another subfield.

Comment: @jonsca thanks for your advice. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of information are you after.  Are you looking for information on how to process the  images from a data processing point of view?

Or from a theory point of view?

Are you looking at satellite images?  if so land or water?

Proprietary software look at ENVI

http://www.exelisvis.com/language/en-us/productsservices/envi.aspx

for free software look at SeaDAS

http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/seadas/

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/

and Hydra

http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/hydra/

Sorry, couldn't add more than 2 hyper-links.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for any information specialized for hyperspectral or multispectral imaging but thought getting those images would be the first step.

Comment: I could probably offer more help if you are a bit more specific.  If not, good luck.